# bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I'm trying execute my RoR application, but when I execute the command: `rails s` The follow error is displayed:

```
/Users/Jarvis/Documents/Projects/Vincubo/vincubo/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]

The most common rails commands are:
 generate    Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")
 console     Start the Rails console (short-cut alias: "c")
 server      Start the Rails server (short-cut alias: "s")
 dbconsole   Start a console for the database specified in config/database.yml
             (short-cut alias: "db")
 new         Create a new Rails application. "rails new my_app" creates a
             new application called MyApp in "./my_app"

In addition to those, there are:
 application  Generate the Rails application code
 destroy      Undo code generated with "generate" (short-cut alias: "d")
 plugin new   Generates skeleton for developing a Rails plugin
 runner       Run a piece of code in the application environment (short-cut alias: "r")
```

But, when I execute the command:

> $ rake rails:update:bin

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0-static/rmagick-2.13.2/RMagick2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0-static/rmagick-2.13.2/RMagick2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0-static/rmagick-2.13.2/RMagick2.bundle
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/rmagick.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
/Users/Jarvis/Documents/Projects/Vincubo/vincubo/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Jarvis/Documents/Projects/Vincubo/vincubo/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/Users/Jarvis/Documents/Projects/Vincubo/vincubo/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
source 'http://rubygems.org'

if RUBY_VERSION =~ /1.9/ # assuming you're running Ruby ~1.9
  Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
  Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
end

gem 'rails', '4.1.2'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

gem 'spring',        group: :development

gem 'cells'
gem 'paperclip'

gem "mail"
gem "jquery-fileupload-rails"

gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails"
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"

gem "rmagick"

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
gem 'pg'
gem 'roadie'
gem 'rubyXL'

gem 'spreadsheet'
gem 'fileutils'
gem 'iconv'
gem 'roo'
```

Comment: have you tried only with rails server?

Comment: show me the same error than 'rails s'

Comment: I think the problem is rmagic, do you have it installed?

Comment: I have installed 'rmagick' , what I can do? @emerak

Comment: Can I see the gemfile?

Comment: @emerak I update the description with the gemfile, the problem with the rmagick is documented here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/30258, but I cant understand how I can apply it

Comment: Mmmm I think it's more a problem related to gem versions, what rails version were you using?

Comment: @emerak the rails version is 4.1.2, I updated the version from the 4.1.0 and all was working good, but with the update, some references are broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a configuration file under the

```
config/initializers
```

I got this error when I removed dragonfly_s3, dragonfly and s3_direct_upload

After doing a bundle install and  doing rails s

I got the same error

Deleted the initializer files and it worked